# A problem of Volterra integral equation.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, cauchy-problem

How can I prove this problem?:

> Consider the Volterra integral equation $$x(t)=g(t)+\int_{[a,b]}f(s,x(s))ds, \quad t \in [a,b],$$where $g \in C([a,b];\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $f:[a,b]\times \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is continuous and $$||f(s,x)-f(s,y)||\leq L||x-y||, \quad \forall s \in [a,b], x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}.$$Prove that there is a unique solution $x\in C([a,b];\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

**My attempt:** Consider the sequence of functions $x_{n}: I \to \mathbb{R}$, $n=0,1,\ldots,$ defined iteratively as follows $$x_{0}(t)=g(t), \quad \forall t \in I,$$ $$x_{n+1}(t)=g(t)+\int_{[0,t]}f(s,x_{n}(s))ds, \quad t \in [a,b] \wedge \forall n=0,1,\ldots$$Now, I need to prove that $x_{n+1}$ is uniformly convergent.

But I don't know how to continue from there.
Initially I thought that this is not Volterra equation and I was thinking this is nonlinear inhomogeneous Fredholm integral equation, and therefore there are a few assumptions to make the existence of such solutions (not for all $L$), but I don't know.

Comment: You can try to show that the sequence is Cauchy in each point, and then show uniform convergence to the pointwise limit.

Comment: Another question: is it Volterra equation or nonlinear inhomogeneous Fredholm integral equation?

Comment: I am not that well versed in these concepts, but going by the wikipedia entries, it seems like neither.

Comment: Can you try to prove the Volterra integral equation satisfies contraction mapping, since contraction mapping theorem guarantees a unique solution in $C\left([a,b]\right)$?

Comment: Yes, but in that case this problems is not Volterra equation. This problems should be nonlinear inhomogeneous Fredholm integral equation, and therefore there are a few assumptions to make the existence of such solutions (not for all L), but I don't sure about it.